# AWS Console and Eclipse View show different things

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Both the images below were taken at the same time after refreshing both the browser and the eclipse console multiple times. Why the two different statuses? Does the web console have a large delay or lag?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your aws console is displaying the status from us-east-1 and your eclipse view from us-west-2.

The console uses the same Apis that are available to everyone - it shouldn't display results that are any different.